# How do you pass parameters TO a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I have seen articles on how to add parameters to shortcodes, so that I can say something like `[my-shortcode post_id=7]`, to pass a post ID to a shortcode.

Let's say I have a form on my page and the user enters something or selects something and based on that I want to refresh the content represented by the shortcode using user-supplied parameter(s).

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a form that sends the data in the following way:

```
<form method="post" name="car-select" action="<?php echo site_url('/my-page/'); ?>">
    <select name="make">
        <option value="benz">Benz</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find my dream car!"/>
</form>
```

Now you want to query some posts based on users choice right? This is where `$_POST` comes in handy:

```
add_shortcode('my-shortcode','my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function($atts){
    // Get the ID from shortcode
    $id = $atts['post_id'];
    // Check if the form data has been sent
    if (isset($_POST['make']) && $id){
        $car_manufacturer = $_POST['make'];
        //Now, you have the form's data. Do whatever you want with it
        return $my_shortcode_values;
    }
}
```

You have to extend this code to fit your needs, such as defining what to do if there is no form data.

Comment: I can see that this answers my question, but I don't have to pass a parameter to the shortcode, the function just has to get the POST data and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if you use a $_GET instead.
The value will remain even if user refresh (F5) the page.

```
if (isset($_GET ['make']) && $id){
        $car_manufacturer = $_GET ['make'];
        //Now, you have the form's data. Do whatever you want with it
        return $my_shortcode_values;
    }
```